# How to organize CakePHP code?

Tags: php, cakephp, transactions

I'm starting with CakePHP. I have very simple models:

- Users
- Companies
- CompaniesUsers (a hasMany through relation between Users and Companies)

I create a user, and when I login as this user, if there isn't any relation between User and Companies, I'm redirected to the add action of the Companies controller. This is all done, and working well.

My "big" problem is: When I save a company, I must save the company's data AND the relation between the current user and the created company. This all must be done inside a transaction, because I don't want "orphan" companies. But where should I put this code? Create a save() function in the Companies model and create the relation after saving? Create an afterSave() function in the Companies model? Put all the code in the CompaniesController's add action? I don't think this last option is a good idea, the bussiness logic must be in the model, isn't it?

I know that this must be a very basic question, but I'm new to CakePHP and to MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This all must be done inside a transaction, because I don't want "orphan" companies

### Use saveAssociated

CakePHP already provides a function which does exactly what you're asking for: [saveAssociated](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array) (also accessible via [saveAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array))

> Model::saveAssociated(array $data = null, array $options = array())

The options array has multiple keys, of most relevance:

> atomic: If true (default), will attempt to save all records in a single transaction. Should be set to false if database/table does not support transactions.

As such there's no need for any extra code, simply call `saveAssociated` where right now `save` is being called.

### Usage

Ensure the saved data is the right format for a [hasMany through relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-hasmany-through-data) - if in doubt it should be the same format as a find containing the same data:

```
class ExampleController extends AppController {

    function example() {
        $data = array(
            'Company' => array(
                'name' => 'My Company'
            ),
            'CompaniesUser' => array(
                'user_id' => 'My User Id'
            )
        );

        $this->Company->saveAssociated($data);
    }

}
```

This will either save the new company *and* the relation to the given user - or fail modifying nothing in the database.

Comment: Great! So I must create a form for Companies, with all the data for saving a Company. Then, in the controller I assign the current user_id and other related data (like CompaniesUsers role), and call to Company->saveAssociated($this->request->data), isn't it?

Comment: @marccasas in short: yes =)

Answer (score 1):

The answer of your first question is that you don’t need to insert additional code into model, this can be done in controller like this

**CompanyController.php**

```
$datasource = $this->Company->getDataSource();
try{
    $datasource->begin();
    if(!$this->Company->save($data)
        throw new Exception();

    if(!$this->User->save($data_one)
        throw new Exception();

    $datasource->commit();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $datasource->rollback();
}
```

The answer for the second question is bit difficult. I personally feel that Cakephp is filled with bad practices. It should follow **Fat Model and Skinny Controller** Concept. If you want to code best practice of MVC, then model layer would contain all business logic unlike cake basic functions.

Comment: I'm very new to CakePHP and I've just started with this application. You said that CakePHP is filled with bad practices. So, which framework (PHP or other languages) do you recomend to me (keep in mind that I wanna build an application with lots of models and business logic)?

Comment: If you are new to PHP, then it does not matter what framework you choose for development. Other PHP frameworks might not be easy for you for starter.

Comment: No, I'm not new to CakePHP and I'm not new to software development (more than 10 years of experience). I'm new to MVC web applications & CakePHP (I've already tried RoR and Grails, but I've found CakePHP easier to develop & deploy)

Comment: Yes it is really easy to code and make application. You can try Zend

Comment: I've thinking about this answer, and I think that this logic must go inside the model... Do you have any example of how to do this?

Comment: yes you can, put the code in model and wrap it with a function. call this function in controller and pass array of data as argument.

Comment: It's kind of weird to provide an answer saying `you don’t need to insert additional code into model, this can be done in controller` providing code that accesses a datasource in a controller and in the same answer say `It should follow Fat Model and Skinny Controller Concept` - the code you're providing is in direct contradiction to this principle (i.e. the controller is the **wrong** place to put code like that).