# Error using saveAssociated with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have three simple models:

- Users
- Companies
- CompaniesUsers (hasMany through relation between Users and Companies)

As AD7six tell me in this question ([How to organize CakePHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616933/how-to-organize-cakephp-code)), I'm using saveAssociated() to persist a Company and a CompanyUsers (with a "link" to Users), but I'm doing something wrong:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['CompanyUser'] = array (
            'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
            'user_role' => 'admin'
        );

        debug($this->request->data);
        if ($this->Company->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
    }
}
```

The Company is saved (looking at the SQL log), but CompanyUser not. The content of $this->request->data is:

```
array(
'Company' => array(
    'name' => 'will this work?',
    'vat_number' => 'maybe...'
),
'CompanyUser' => array(
    'user_id' => '1',
    'user_role' => 'admin'
)
)
```

And the problem is that the content of the CompanyUser "key" is ignored. Cake tries to add a CompanyUser, but only filling the "company_id", "created" and "modified" fields, so MySQL throws an "Integrity Constraint Violation" for the "user_id" field. And the "user_role" (a field of CompanyUser) isn't added.

What I'm doing wrong, here?

Comment: I think you have your data organized incorrectly.  Company should hasMany CompanyUser, correct?  Then the array should probably be something more like `array('Company' => array(...), 'CompanyUser' => array(array('user_id' => 1, 'user_role' => 'admin'), ...);`

Comment: you're right!! please, post your answer as a "complete answer" so I can vote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving a hasMany relationship, the array should look like this:

```
array(
  'Company' => array(...), 
  'CompanyUser' => array(
      array('user_id' => 1, 'user_role' => 'admin'), 
      ...
    )
);
```